# Why does this MCMC algorithm to estimate parameters of a linear equation not converge to the posterior distribution?

Tags: markov-chains, monte-carlo, parameter-estimation

As a kind of proof of principle I'm trying to estimate the parameters of a linear equation (before moving on to ODEs) using Markov Chain Monte Carlo sampling. The post that I am following can be found at this link https://sciencehouse.wordpress.com/2010/06/23/mcmc-and-fitting-models-to-data/

Essentially what I am doing is not working and I'm wondering if anybody can spot the reason why?

**The model**
$$y=mx+c$$ 
evaluated at $m=2$ and $c=4$ as a simple linear model:

**The Algorithm**

1. Initialize $m0$ and $c0$ to be random values (I arbitrarily chose 25 for both) and evaluate a function that measures the descrepancy between the experimental and simulated data (where of course in this case the experpimental data is also simulated with the correct parameters). I use the sum of squares $SSR$:

$$ SSR=\frac{(SimulatedData-ExperimentalData)^2}{2*sigma^2}$$

Because there is no experimental error in this model, sigma was arbitrarily chosen to be 0.0001 in all cases.

2. I then begin a loop and sample from prior $π_m$ and $π_c$, producing $m_prop$ and $c_prop$ respectively, which are both uniformly distributed between 0 and 100.
3. Calculate the $SSR$ with the sampled parameters
4. Calculate the likelihood ratio $LR$:
   $$ LR=exp[\frac{(-ln(SSR proposed)+ln(SSR current)}{2*sigma^2}]$$
5. Randomly accept the new parameters by sampling again from the uniform distribution between 0 and 1 (call this $r$). If $LR>r$ the new parameters are accepted and $m_prop$ becomes $m0$ and $c_prop$ becomes $c0$

As a side question, why do some people say the acceptance probability is $min(1,LR)$ whereas the post that I'm following uses random acceptance?

6. Iterate until convergence

**Results**

[image]
[image]

**---------edit--------------**

Courtesy of Joriki's answer, I have removed the $2*sigma^2$ term from the likelihood function such that step 4 now reads:

4. Calculate the likelihood ratio $LR$:
   $$ LR=exp[(-ln(SSR proposed)+ln(SSR current)]$$

This has considerably improved the results:
[image]

[image]

**Matlab Code**

For completeness and to give the details of the algorithm, here is the code I'm using to generate the plots:

```
interval=1:100;
y=mx_plus_c((2),interval,(4));
n=1e5; %iterations
results=zeros(n,8);
m0=25;
c0=25;
y_sim=mx_plus_c(m0,interval,c0);
SSR_cur=SSR(y,y_sim,0.0001);
mlb=log(1);   %lb lower bound, ub upper bound respoectively 
mub=log(100);
clb=log(1);
cub=log(100);
for i=1:n,
    m_prop   =   (mlb+(mub-mlb).*rand(1,1)   )   ;
    c_prop   =    (clb+(cub-clb).*rand(1,1)   )  ;
    SSR_prop=SSR(y,mx_plus_c(m_prop,interval,c_prop),0.0001);
    likelihood_ratio=exp((-log(SSR_prop)+log(SSR_cur)));
    r   =    ( (0+(1-0).*rand(1,1)   )  );
    if likelihood_ratio>r,
        m0=m_prop;
        c0=c_prop;
        SSR_cur=SSR_prop;
    end
    results(i,1)=m0;
    results(i,2)=c0;
    results(i,3)=SSR_cur;
    results(i,4)=m_prop;
    results(i,5)=c_prop;
    results(i,6)=SSR_prop;
    results(i,7)=likelihood_ratio;
    results(i,8)=r;

end
% results
figure(2)
hist(results(:,1),1000)
title('Distribution of m parameters','fontsize',16) 
xlabel('Parameter Values','fontsize',16)
ylabel('Frequency','fontsize',16)

figure(3)
hist(results(:,2),1000)
title('Distribution of c parameters','fontsize',16) 
xlabel('Parameter Values','fontsize',16)
ylabel('Frequency','fontsize',16)
```

Where: `mx_plus_c` is a Matlab function:

```
function y=mx_plus_c(m,x,c)
y=m*[x]+c;
end
```

And `SSR` is also a Matlab function

```
function chi2 = SSR(sim,exp,sigma)
chi2 =sum(  (  ([sim]-[exp]).^2)./ ( 2*sigma^2) ) ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problems – without seeing the details of the simulation, it's hard to tell which, if any, of them are causing the failure.

- You're choosing the parameters anew every time – you're not making use of the previous progress in improving the parameters. The idea is to propose new parameters in the vicinity of the present parameters, not sample them from the same distribution every time. (What exactly the "vicinity" is depends on the specific application, and you can change it over time to take big steps at first and then increasingly small steps.)
- I don't think you should be taking the logarithm and dividing by $2\sigma^2$ again in computing the likelyhood ratio – you should just be exponentiating the difference between the squared errors. Since your $\sigma$ is tiny, this may be causing problems.
- You don't say how you determine convergence. With that tiny value of $\sigma$ and that broad prior that you never change, if you terminate after a certain number of failed attempts to change the parameters, this may just be leaving you in some random place because you're unlikely to make progress in each step.

Generally, to debug this sort of thing, you should look at the values as they evolve and try to check at each stage whether what is happening corresponds to what you expected to happen, instead of just making one big plot in the end that doesn't show what went wrong.

As to your side question, "why do some people say the acceptance probability is $\min(1,LR)$ whereas the post that I'm following uses random acceptance?", I don't understand the question – using an acceptance probability of $\min(1,LR)$ *is* random acceptance (namely with a certain probability), and it's exactly what you're doing: If $LR\gt1$, you always accept, and otherwise you accept with probability $LR$.

Comment: Hi joriki, thanks for responding. I have addressed your second bullet point which has improved the simulation considerably (see edit above). To give you some more information, I have posted the code I'm using to generate the plots. What now confuses me is why does this code give me fairly good results even though i'm not making use of previous progress, as you  note in your first bullet point?

Comment: @user3059024: Well, you're trying $100000$ times, you're bound to hit some reasonable values even trying anew each time. But that's terribly expensive; with that amount of time a proper Monte Carlo should get you much better results. By the way, note that the whole probabilistic acceptance makes no sense this way -- if the proposed values don't depend on the old values, you should just be storing the best value seen so far; the probabilistic acceptance is for overcoming barriers in the landscape, but you're not actually exploring a landscape this way.

Comment: @user3059024: Also, you're still taking logarithms of the errors; I don't see why you'd want to do that.

Comment: @user3059024: P.S.: You say you're sampling uniformly between $0$ and $100$, but it seems you're actually sampling uniformly between $0$ and $\log100$?